# Eclipse Compiler error saying connection variable cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

this is a Java Code i wrote in Eclipse to retrieve information from a MySQL Database.. But the Compiler is giving an error saying conn cannot be resolved to a type.. can anyone pls tel me what i may be doin wrng??

```
import java.sql.*;

public class plh {

static Connection conn=null;
static Statement s=null;

public static void main(String[] args){


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wonkashop","root", "");
        String st= new String("select * from users;");
        s= new conn.createStatement(st);//ERROR.. why??

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to Database");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here in the  line

```
   s= new conn.createStatement(st);//ERROR.. why??
```

there is no need for new `keyword`

like

```
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(credentials);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(st);
```

Comment: This will result in compilation error. Moreover *createStatement its already returning an Object if PreparedStatement.* is also wrong !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and surfing by Internet triying to get a solution without successful I put these imports and it works for me.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

I hope this can help more people.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `new` keyword from your line of code. You need to get the `Statement` as :

```
 s= conn.createStatement(); // createStatement doesn't take a String argument
```

`DriverManager.getConnection()` already returns a `Connection` object , which you have referenced by the identifier `conn` , hence use it to get the `Statement` .

If you want to pass the sql query string , use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement`.
That is [`Connection#prepareStatement(sql)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29).

**Statement :**

```
final String st= "select * from users;";
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(st);
```

**PreparedStatement:**

```
final String st= "select * from users;";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(st);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
s= new conn.createStatement(st);//ERROR.. why??
```

to

```
s= conn.createStatement();
```

[Connection#createStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement)

> Returns a new default Statement object.

Answer (score 0):

Just `conn.createStatement();`. Don't put `new` here, because you're not instantiating a class.

You should only write `new` before the name of a class, because it creates an object of that class.  But here, `conn` is not the name of a class - it's just the name of a variable that references an existing object of some class.

Comment: FYI createStatement() doesn't take any argument

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wonkashop", "root", "");
           st= "select * from users";
           s =  conn.createStatement();// fixed
           ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(st);
           while(rs.next()){
               //Retrieve by column name
               int id  = rs.getInt("id");
               String name = rs.getInt("name");

          }

    }
```